# Slight animation and easing on page resize

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

OK, so this is something I recently noticed working on someone else's code who used boostrap to build their site. I checked the new bootstrap and it doesn't seem to do this anymore though.

When you resize the site's window elements don't just jump to new widths and heights, it's like it eases into the new width or height.

What exactly are they doing here, is this JS or CSS?

Comment: It's probably transitions.

Comment: @artm thats what I thought, but then im missing a global setting in my css, because it's def not on each and every element

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: @artm looking at that now, added `* {
 @include transition(width 0.2s, height 0.2s, background-color 0.2s, transform 0.2s);
 @include transition-timing-function(ease-in);
}` and it's getting there, just doesnt quite have that bounce just yet.. looking into different transitions now..